# opensuse leap 15.4, automatic wifi connection to known sites using eth0

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, opensuse

I only connect to the internet via wifi, and Yast Network shows the following info on my internet connectivity:

> RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
> (Not connected)
> MAC : fc:34:97:80:f1:82
> BusID : 0000:01:00.0

> Device Name: eth0
> Configured without an address
> Started automatically at boot

> Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz
> MAC : f0:9e:4a:66:02:5b
> BusID : 0000:00:14.3

> Device Name: wlan1
> Configured with dhcp
> Started automatically at boot

Which works fine, except that if I go to a different wifi hotspot, even one I have used in the past, I have to use Yast Network to access it and re-enter the network name and its password to get a connection. How can I modify this setup so that wifi connects automatically to any previously used hotspot?

Comment: I think you want to switch to Network Manager rather than use wicked.

Comment: Thank you again. You are as useful as a 4 year course in IT. If you want to enter it as a solution again, I will rate it as the right answer.

Comment: @Bib is correct though... NetworkManager and Wicked are for two different purposes... Wicked is great for servers and stuff that doesn't move or change often and are setup by the administrator that doesn't change or allow the user to change it, but Network Manager is more for desktop/mobile use as it can do things like remember multiple wifi networks, connect to them automatically, and allowing the user to make changes in the network connection. You are literally asking for wicked to do what it is designed NOT to do, but what Network Manager *IS* designed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You want to switch to Network Manager rather than use wicked.

Wicked  just uses a single entry and cannot configured with multiple connections.

Network Manager however, can.